# Eloquent: How to combine eager loading and filter by pivot?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relationship between models.  For a given model instance, I know how to filter the related models according to the value of a pivot.  For example, in the case of users and roles, I would use:

```
User->roles()->wherePivot('admin',1);
```

Similarly, I know how to eager load all roles for a set of users:

```
User::where('active',1)->with('roles')->get();
```

What I am trying to do is combine these two concepts.  For example, how do I retrieve a set of users with their eagerly loaded roles, where the users are filtered according to a field on the pivot?

I realise I can do this easily enough with raw SQL, but I would prefer to use Eloquent if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restrict your eager loaded relations using a closure.

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
        return $query->wherePivot('admin', 1);
    }])
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

You can also query relations using `whereHas`.

```
$users = User::with('roles')
    ->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        return $query->wherePivot('admin', 1);
    })
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a closure in to with when eager loading to add clauses to the query:

```
        User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('admin', 1);
        }])->where('active', 1)->get();
```